# How to change the date format in Microsoft Word 'track changes' balloons

Tags: microsoft-word, office-for-mac

I'm using Microsoft Word for Mac, version 14.3.8.

I've got track changes enabled, and it's flagging my changes with little balloons on the right hand-side.  All well and good so far.

Then it tells me that one of my changes was made on 2nd July 2014 - 2/7/14.  Well that's in the future, and I definitely changed it today.  Ah yes it's the pesky dd/mm/yy - used by only 2 countries in the world, but the default setting for most software.

How do I change the date format for these balloons? The language of the document is marked as UK english.

Answer (score 1):

Well on Windows, that is set from the System's International settings not those of the document.

Can't say for sure on a Mac though I'm afraid.

Of course, it is entirely possible that the Office for Mac programmers are so US-centric that it wasn't tested with other date formats!

Personally, I prefer yyyy-mm-dd ISO format for short dates for the avoidance of doubt :)